# как перестать получать 401 error api app.poizon.com?

Tags: python, http-status-code-401

```
def return_sign(raw_sign_code_str):

   m = hashlib.md5()
   m.update(raw_sign_code_str.encode("utf8"))
   sign = m.hexdigest()
   return sign


def brand_list_load_more_data(page, sortType, sortMode, catId, unionId, title=''):

    sign = return_sign('catId{}limit20page{}showHot-1sortMode{}sortType{}title{}unionId{}19bc545a393a25177083d4a748807cc0'.format(
                       catId, page, sortMode, sortType, title, unionId
   ))
    print(sign)
    url = 'https://app.poizon.com/api/v1/h5/search/fire/search/list?' \
         'sign={}&title={}&page={}&sortType={}' \
         '&sortMode={}&limit=20&showHot=-1&catId={}&unionId={}'.format(sign, title, page, sortType, sortMode, catId, unionId)
    res_data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    print(res_data)

def product_detail_data(spuId, propertyValueId, productSourceName=''):

    post_data = dict()
    post_data['spuId'] = spuId
    post_data['productSourceName'] = productSourceName
    post_data['propertyValueId'] = propertyValueId
    post_data['sign'] = return_sign(
       'productSourceName{}propertyValueId{}spuId{}19bc545a393a25177083d4a748807cc0'.format(productSourceName, propertyValueId, spuId))
    post_data = str(post_data).encode('utf-8')
    res_data = requests.post(product_detail_url, headers=headers, data=post_data).text
    print(res_data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    brand_list_load_more_data(page=0, sortType=1, sortMode=1, catId=0, unionId=144)
```

все перепробобовал, прилетает ошибка `{"code":403,"status":403,"msg":"请求已拒绝","error":true}`

Не могу документацию найти

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#401